# Glib: Memory leak when creating GDBusProxy

Tags: c, linux, glib, dbus

I'm trying to call `DBus` method of `NetworkManager` by using `Glib-Dbus` in `linux`. When I create a `GDBusProxy` by **g_dbus_proxy_new_sync** and then free it by **g_object_unref**, the new created `GDBusProxy` seems not to be freed. I have used `pmap -x <pid>` to display memory usage of my process and the `RSS` value increased continuously. Can someone help me?

Here is the code that causes the problem:

```
    int main (int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        GDBusConnection * connection = NULL;
        GDBusProxy * proxy = NULL;
        GError * error = NULL;

        connection = g_bus_get_sync(G_BUS_TYPE_SYSTEM,
                                    NULL,
                                    &error);
        g_assert_no_error(error);
        error = NULL;

        while (1)
        {
            proxy = g_dbus_proxy_new_sync(connection,
                                          G_DBUS_PROXY_FLAGS_DO_NOT_LOAD_PROPERTIES |      G_DBUS_PROXY_FLAGS_DO_NOT_CONNECT_SIGNALS,
                                          NULL,
                                          "org.freedesktop.NetworkManager",
                                          "/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings",
                                          "org.freedesktop    .NetworkManager.Settings",
                                          NULL,
                                          NULL);

            g_assert(proxy != NULL);
            g_object_unref(proxy);

        }

        g_object_unref(connection);

        return 0;
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a patch attached to this bug report (which has been applied to the glib git repository) which should solve your problem:
https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=758641

Presumably it will be in glib-2.46.3 and/or glib-2.48.  It seems just to have been merged in the glib-2.46 branch.

Answer (score 3):

GLib and associated libraries do not use the system `malloc/free` pair; they usually resort to an internal slab allocator. This means that just reading the output of `top` or `pmap` is not in any way useful to determine whether GLib, or any application using GLib, is actually leaking:

You should use [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/), instead, and make sure to read [this wiki page](https://wiki.gnome.org/Valgrind) for some of the details on how to use Valgrind with applications using GLib.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Valgrind to find out the memory leak in your program.